# Randomized Quicksort not generated random pivot

Tags: java, data-structures

I am making Randomized Quicksort. I am exchanging randomized index number index with last index. and then applying uicksort. But I am getting different output on each Execution. Can you help me?

```
public class Quick {

public void quickSort(int arr[], int begin, int end) {

    if (begin < end) {
        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int i = random.nextInt(end);

        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;

        int partitionIndex = partition(arr, begin, end);
        quickSort(arr, begin, partitionIndex-1);
        quickSort(arr, partitionIndex+1, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use this: `int i = rand.nextInt((end - begin) + 1) + begin;`

Comment: can you explain this?

Comment: you need to pick random values from [begin, end), not [0, end).